# Adding references in Visual Studio project template?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, project-template

I'm creating a multi-project template for VS2015 where one of the created projects references the other. How do I add the reference using the template?

If I add the reference using the VS GUI it will add the following to the .vcxproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="path\xyz.vcxproj">
<Project>{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}</Project>
</ProjectReference>
```

And the GUID is a valid one, since VS knows the GUID of the referenced project. When I create the new projects from template I don't know what GUID will be chosen for the newly created project, so I can't add a valid GUID by using the template parameters. I can easily add the `Include="..."` part correctly, but the GUID I don't have.

I couldn't find much info on the `<ProjectReference>` tag either, but it seems that a valid GUID is required, leaving the `<Project>` tag out causes the reference to not work, and same happens if I use all zeros GUID.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I have 2 project references in the main project. It worked for me in Visual Studio 2019, Net Core 3. as @skaddy answer, but not after several Visual Studio restarts and finally machine restart (that sucks).

The difference is that **I did not care about the guid** I  just let Visual Studio care about that.

Steps

1. In the solution template, the Root.vstemplate I set CopyParameters="true"

```
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.API" CopyParameters="true">
        APITemplate\MyTemplate.vstemplate
    </ProjectTemplateLink>
```

2. I ensure that ReplaceParameters="true" was there in the main project template ( it was since the beginning).

```
    <TemplateContent>
        <Project TargetFileName="APITemplate.csproj" File="APITemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
            ...
        <\Project>
        ...
    <\TemplateContent>
```

3. In the main .csproj file I look at the references and change them with the parameters

From this

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Data\Data.csproj"/>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Service\Service.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>
```

To this

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\$ext_safeprojectname$.Data\$ext_safeprojectname$.Data.csproj"/>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\$ext_safeprojectname$.Service\$ext_safeprojectname$.Service.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Again, for me the parameters just works after machine restart.

Comment: Just make sure the tag of <name> and <defaultname> inside template data does not have an addentilanal prefix or postfix it just should be just <Name>$safeprojectname$</Name>

Comment: This worked for me. Tip: at least on VisualStudio 2022, you can prevent the reboot by deleting the c:\users\{user_id}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.x_yyyyy\NpdProjectTemplateCache_en-US file as well as the ProjectTemplatesCache_{xxx} directory, located under the same path.

Comment: +1 for the $ext_safeprojectname$ reference. That was exactly what I was missing. I couldn't find docs on that anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the GUIDs in the solution template and pass them to the projects. Therefor you need the parameter CopyParameters in the ProjectTemplateLink in Solution Template.
Example:

```
<ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Data"  CopyParameters="true">
```

Your project template has to replace parameters

```
<Project TargetFileName="Data.vbproj" File="Data.vbproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
```

Now you can access the parameters from solution template inside the project file and set the external guid parameter (note the acces to the external parameter have a "$ext_")

```
 <ProjectGuid>{$ext_guid1$}</ProjectGuid>
```

For the project with the reference you use the ProjectReference inside ItemGroup

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\$ext_safeprojectname$.Data\$ext_safeprojectname$.Data.vbproj">
    <Project>{$ext_guid1$}</Project>
    <Name>$ext_safeprojectname$.Data</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

It worked for me using Visual Studio 2017 with .NET Framework 4.5.2